# IdentityServer 4, how to add Custom Login page

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, blazor, abp

I wish to customize the IdentityServer 4 and use custom pages for login / registration / lost password / etc... ( FYI, I use Blazor, but it should be the same ! ).

***Example***
By example, for now, I use the following code:

`Challenge(authProps, "oidc");`

But it redirects to a pre-defined login page, how can I change this?

***Information***
I have searched for some information, I have seen that some peoples use the following

`.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "http://..../MyLoginPage";`

My problem is that I use abp.io, they provides an IdentityServer, but I have no access to the ***AddIdentityServer*** code, it is hardcoded somewhere and I have no access to it (AbpIdentityServerDomainModule.cs) !

So, I'm looking for a way to redefine the login page !

Comment: Can you post the initialization code ? I mean how you setup adp ?

Comment: You can delete this question, it is duplicate. Sorry

Comment: Can you give us the question's link it duplicates ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the following in the Startup.cs

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config =>
{
    config.Cookie.Name = "IdentityServer.Cookie";
    config.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    config.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
});
```

Comment: What about using a custom Angular page for login?

Comment: It does not matter. You can have an API endpoint that maps this route to your function, then you can query the route with fetch or something like that.

Comment: Any example please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example you can make an action in a controller like: 
[Route("Auth/Login")]
[HttpPost]
public async IActionResult Foo(@Params) {
 // code logic
}

Then you can access this from your client side as :
http.post('host:port/Auth/Login', {username, password})

Answer (score 6):

You can solve your problem by implementing ***Scaffolding***.

**Identity server doc says**
"Applications that include Identity can apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL). You might want to generate source code so you can modify the code and change the behavior."

So you can change UI, end point and its behavior as your need.

[Here is doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-with-authorization)